react-date-range labels for ranges
Curious how I can add labels to the date ranges when there are multiple.  I.e. I would like to write "Outer Date Range" above/next to the first range and "Inner Date Range" above/next to the second range.
                <DateRangePicker
                    minDate={new Date(data.deployment.travelStartDate)}
                    maxDate={new Date(data.deployment.travelEndDate)}
                    onChange={handleSelect}
                    ranges={ranges}
                    rangeColors={rangeColors}
                    shownDate={new Date(data.deployment.startDate)}
                    staticRanges={[]}
                    inputRanges={[]}
                />


